# How to make this watermark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, watermark

I'm going to write a lecture note . I'd like to make create a watermark like this but i don't know how to do it. Can you help me to draw this watermark?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Which part do you define as the watermark?

Comment: Oh the words on the left hand side of this page.

Comment: Do you want this on all pages?

Comment: Yes, i want this on all pages.

Comment: watermarks near the margin are not useful enough for preventing copyright issues. It will be better if you put the watermarks that blends with the contents.

Answer (score 15):

Welcome! You can do that e.g. with `eso-pic` and `tikz`. The distance to this watermark to the text is specified in `([xshift=-1ex]current page text area.west)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<- only to add some text
\AddToShipoutPicture{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \node[anchor=south,rotate=90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
 (AE) at ([xshift=-1ex]current page text area.west){Albert Einstein};
 \draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- ++ (0,4)
   (AE.west) -- ++ (0,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\section{Blub}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For different "watermarks" on even vs. odd pages, you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<- only to add some text
\AddToShipoutPicture{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\ifodd\value{page}
 \node[anchor=south,rotate=90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
 (AE) at ([xshift=-1em]current page text area.west){Albert Einstein};
 \draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- ++ (0,4)
   (AE.west) -- ++ (0,-4);
\else
 \node[anchor=south,rotate=-90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
 (CFG) at ([xshift=1em]current page text area.east){Carl Friedrich Gauss};
 \draw[very thick,pink] (CFG.west) -- ++ (0,4)
   (CFG.east) -- ++ (0,-4);
\fi   
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\section{Blub}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If i want to make the different between odd pages and even pages, how to do it?

Comment: @129492 I added something for that case.

Comment: Thank you for your support @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Equal to the height of the paper or the text area? In the first case `\draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- (AE.east|-current page.north)
   (AE.west) -- ++ (AE.east|-current page.south);` and in the second case `\draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- (AE.east|-current page text area.north)
   (AE.west) -- ++ (AE.east|-current page text area.south);`.

Comment: Thank you very much.