# Tikznode and positioning on A4paper

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found for a watermark the following [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519678/48642):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<- only to add some text
\AddToShipoutPicture{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \ifodd\value{page}
        \node[anchor=south,rotate=90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
        (AE) at ([xshift=-1em]current page text area.west){Albert Einstein};
        \draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- ++ (0,4)
        (AE.west) -- ++ (0,-4);
        \else
        \node[anchor=south,rotate=-90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
        (CFG) at ([xshift=1em]current page text area.east){Carl Friedrich Gauss};
        \draw[very thick,pink] (CFG.west) -- ++ (0,4)
        (CFG.east) -- ++ (0,-4);
        \fi   
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=1cm}
    \lipsum[2-5]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This looks almost perfect except a tiny detail. The positioning is done relative to the given side geometry. Since I have some pages which have a different settings the watermark seems quite odd - especially when on these special pages only one graphic is inserted. There the overlapping doesn't matter.

Is there a way to position the `\node` in a fixed way? e.g. 1.5cm left (or right) and in the middle of the page (which could be calculated manually as well).

**UPDATE**
I've updated the example to contain more than just 2 pages. I would like to have on page 1 and page 3 exactly the same positions of the watermark - despite the `geometry` settings.

Comment: Does this answer help? [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89592](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89592/110998) It uses the node `(currentpage)` and its anchors.

Comment: Something like `\node[rotate=90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] at (current page.center)` won't help much. Or do you mean some other syntax?

Comment: why do you use `current page text area.west` if you don't want a placement relative to the text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the watermark relative to `(current page)` instead of `(current page text area)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<- only to add some text
\AddToShipoutPicture{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \ifodd\value{page}
        \node[anchor=south,rotate=90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
        (AE) at ([xshift=3em]current page.west){Albert Einstein};
        \draw[very thick,pink] (AE.east) -- ++ (0,4)
        (AE.west) -- ++ (0,-4);
        \else
        \node[anchor=south,rotate=-90,pink,font=\sffamily\Huge] 
        (CFG) at ([xshift=-3em]current page.east){Carl Friedrich Gauss};
        \draw[very thick,pink] (CFG.west) -- ++ (0,4)
        (CFG.east) -- ++ (0,-4);
        \fi   
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=1cm}
    \lipsum[2-5]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for the full sample.

Comment: `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}` should be replaced by `\usepackage{tikz}` ?

Comment: @BlackMild Thanks, changed.